# VS Code is not able to connect to Remote Ubuntu machine from mac

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, vscode-remote

I am using the [Remote-SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) extension and trying to connect to a ubuntu server from vscode running in a macbook

VSCode shows the error message "Could not fetch the remote environment"

And shows the message "Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: Time limit reached)"

I have increased the connection timeout to 60s as suggested in the remote ssh troubleshooting steps, but still face this issue.

When I start the session in vscode, I can see the following logs,

```
717b5473e20d: running
Acquiring lock on /home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/vscode-remote-lock.usernameRedacted.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
Installing to /home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f...
717b5473e20d%%1%%
Downloading with wget
Download complete
717b5473e20d%%2%%
tar --version:
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
Checking /home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log and /home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.pid for a running server
Starting server with command... /home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown  --port=0 &> "/home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log" < /dev/null
printenv:
    SHELL=/bin/bash
    PWD=/home/usernameRedacted
    LOGNAME=usernameRedacted
    XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
    MOTD_SHOWN=pam
    HOME=/home/usernameRedacted
    LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server
    SSH_CONNECTION=ip1Redacted 54773 ip2Redacted 22
    XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
    USER=usernameRedacted
    SHLVL=0
    XDG_SESSION_ID=97
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1003
    SSH_CLIENT=ip1Redacted 54773 22
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus
    OLDPWD=/home/usernameRedacted/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f
    _=/usr/bin/printenv
Spawned remote server: 272459
Waiting for server log...
 
*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
*
 
717b5473e20d: start
webUiAccessToken====
listeningOn==39185==
osReleaseId==ubuntu==
arch==x86_64==
tmpDir==/run/user/1003==
platform==linux==
unpackResult==success==
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime==402==
installTime==706==
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==208==
717b5473e20d: end
```

I can see the following process running on the remote host

```
redactedUser@redactedHostname:~$ ps -ef | grep vscode
redactedUser   272459  272399  0 09:50 ?        00:00:00 sh /home/redactedUser/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/server.sh --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0
redactedUser   272466  272459  0 09:50 ?        00:00:00 /home/redactedUser/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/node /home/redactedUser/.vscode-server/bin/e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f/out/vs/server/main.js --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0
```

Also, here is the server log

```
redactedUser@redactedHostname:~$ cat ~/.vscode-server/.e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f.log


*
* Visual Studio Code Server
*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/license
*


IP Address: redacted
Extension host agent listening on 39185


[09:50:19] Extension host agent started.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Tunneling was disabled which caused this issue.

As a fix I had to enable Tunneling by editing /etc/sshd_config

Following settings fixed the issue for me:

[image]

Related Github issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4176